# Scikit-learn pipeline + custom transformer function

Tags: python, oop, scikit-learn, nlp, pipeline

I am trying to create my own function to process some text understand, therefore I have to understand how to use `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin`:

After reading and try I am receiving this message:

> **"/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
> 189     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
> 190     a replacement string to be used."""
> --> 191     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
> 192
> 193 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):
>
> TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object"**

what I want to do is :

1. create a class object able to process the text and then use it with pipeline
2. I don't understand how to fit  and transform are different, I assume fit is only put the data in and transform is the operation/changes on the data.

thank you very much for your help .. here you have some of the code im doing + plus some rows of my data

```
x= corpus.loc [:5 ,'sentences']


0    So there is no way for me to plug it in here i...
1                          Good case, Excellent value.
2                               Great for the jawbone.
3    Tied to charger for conversations lasting more...
4                                    The mic is great.
5    I have to jiggle the plug to get it to line up...
Name: sentences, dtype: object



class cleaning (BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
  def __int__ (self):
    pass

  def fit(self,x,y=None):
    return self
    
  
  def fit_transform(self,x):
    import re
    from nltk.corpus  import stopwords
    import string
    x = map(re.sub(r'(https?://[^\s]+)',"",x))
    x = map(re.sub(r'(https?://[^\s]+)',"",x)) #URl
    x = map(re.sub(r'(?<![@\w])@(\w{1,25})',"",x)) #@MENTION
    x = map(re.sub(r"#(\w+)","",x)) #MENTION
    x = map(''.join(w for w in x if not w.isdigit())) #DIGITS
    x = map(''.join(w for w in x if w not in string.punctuation)) # .?/?
    #x = map(re.lower(),x) # MAKE IT INTO LOWER CASE 
    #x = map(re.sub(r'[^\w ]+',"",x)) #special caracter 
    return x
```

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of problems:

1. `fit_transform`. It should be `transform`, `TransformerMixin` will take care about `fit_transform` automatically. And you have to iterate here, in order to return tranformed iterable. This is why your error.
2. The way you apply `map`. You better drop it altogether.

Once you correct for those you have a working code:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string

class Cleaning(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):

    def __int__ (self):
        pass
    
    @staticmethod
    def _clean_text(x):
        '''
        Args:
            text: string to be cleaned
        Returns:
            string of cleaned text
        '''
        x = re.sub(r'(https?://[^\s]+)',"",x) #URl
        x = re.sub(r'(?<![@\w])@(\w{1,25})',"",x) #@MENTION
        x = re.sub(r"#(\w+)","",x) #MENTION
        x = ''.join(w for w in x if not w.isdigit()) #DIGITS
        x = ''.join(w for w in x if w not in string.punctuation) # .?/?
        #x = map(re.lower(),x) # MAKE IT INTO LOWER CASE 
        #x = map(re.sub(r'[^\w ]+',"",x)) #special caracter 
        x = re.sub(r'\s+',r' ',x)
        return x.strip()

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        '''
        Args:
            x: iterable of strings
        Returns:
            list of transformed text
        '''
        X_ = list()
        for text in X:
            X_.append(self._clean_text(text))
        return X_


cleaning = Cleaning()
out = cleaning.fit_transform(df["Text"])
pprint(out)
```

---

```
['So there is no way for me to plug it in here i',
 'Good case Excellent value',
 'Great for the jawbone',
 'Tied to charger for conversations lasting more',
 'The mic is great',
 'I have to jiggle the plug to get it to line up']
```

Comment: @Marvin Does this answer your question? Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Thank you Very much...!! I am now trying to implement it into my code lines .. thanks...